# Postgres - table stats

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get an information about what tables are queried the most, by what users, what times, how often + what queries were sent.

Is there any source for Postgres I can get all of this information from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see cumulative statistics for table utilization in `pg_stat_user_tables` and for indexes in `pg_stat_user_indexes`.

The workload can be monitored using `pg_stat_statements`, but you have to activate it first.

PostgreSQL does not retain any knowledge which user queries which tables. If you want that, you would have to log all statements and evaluate the log with a tool like pgBadger. Note that logging all statements can put a lot of strain on the database.

Comment: _logging all statements_ - isn't this default behaviour of postgres? I mean that it logs every query? Or it has to be explicitly somehow activated?

Comment: That is not the default. As I said, it would break many busy applications.